# Accessing primary key in Django class based view

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

## Accessing primary keys in Django class based view

Let's start from the beginning. I have 2 models, Recipe, and Ingredient. They look like this.

### In models.py

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text='Enter the name of this recipe')
    description=models.TextField(max_length=75, help_text='Describe your recipe')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('recipe-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk`})

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    recipe=models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['ingredient']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ingredient
```

What I want to be able to do is have a detail view, where I can access the Recipe attributes, like the name and description, as well as, be able to loop through the ingredients. This is what I have working so far:

### In views.py

```
def recipe_detail_view(request, pk):
    recipe = get_object_or_404(Recipe, pk=pk)
    context = {
        'recipe': recipe,
        'ingredients': Ingredient.objects.filter(recipe=pk)
        }
    return render(request, 'recipes/recipe_detail.html', context=context)
```

### In urls.py

```
# ...
path('recipes/<str:pk>', views.recipe_detail_view, name='recipe-detail')
# ...
```

### In template

```
<h1 class="title is-1">{{ recipe.name }}</h1>
<p>{{ recipe.description }}</p>
<h3 class="title">Ingredients</h3>
{% for ingredient in ingredients %}
    <h4 class="">{{ ingredient.ingredient.title }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

I am wondering how I could turn this into a class based view however. More specifically, I am wondering how I can access and pass in the primary key to the filter like so:

```
class RecipeDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Recipe
    template_name = 'recipes/recipe_detail.html'
    context_object_name='recipe'
    extra_context = {
        'ingredients': Ingredient.objects.filter(recipe=pk),
    }
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `get_context_data` and `get_object` to get the data you want to your template.

```py
class RecipeDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Recipe
    template_name = 'recipes/recipe_detail.html'
    context_object_name='recipe'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs)
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['ingredients'] = Ingredient.objects.filter(recipe=self.get_object().pk)
        return ctx
```